# Request.POST.get not working for me in django, returning default value

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get input from a html form in django , python code below:

```
def add(request):
   n = request.POST.get('Username', 'Did not work')
   i = Item(name=n,price=0)
   i.save()
   return render(request,'tarkovdb/test.html')
```

Second pic is my html code:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"› 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384—Vkoo8x4CGs0 OPaXtkKtu6ug5T0eNV6gBiFeWPGFN9Muh0f23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <title>Tarkov Database Web App</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>This is the page to add items</h1> 
            <li><a href="{% url 'tarkovdb:index' s'6}">List of Items in DataBase</a></li> 

<form> 
    <div class="form—group"> 
        <label for&username'> Username: </lable> 
        <input type&text' name='Username' id.'username'> <br><br> 
    </div> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn—primary">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Please **never** post screenshots of your code but paste your code in your question and format it using the formatting tools of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your [method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) attribute to "**post**" on your HTML [form tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp). Like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <!-- your fields here -->
</form>
```

Otherwise you'll be sending a GET request, which is the default value of the [method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) attribute.

PD.: Please paste your code, make it easy for the community to help you. Otherwise you'll get down voted.

Comment: Sorry that was my first post, also when I did this it said there was a CSRF error

Comment: Yeah, you should put `{% csrf_token %}` inside your form. However, that's another question.